# how do I make face recognition with blob oracle

Tags: oracle, blob, face-recognition

I have a row that contains the names and photos of people in Oracle, how do I make face recognition that can recognize names only by taking pictures from the camera ??
what techniques can I use?

Comment: We can use ORDImage to compare images. [Find out more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11689731/146325). However, that's a long way from full-on facial recognition. I don't think there's anything built-in just yet, even in latest 20c. There are non-database solutions which use [Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/datascience/how-to-build-a-face-recognition-application-with-4-lines-of-code) [libraries](https://waslleysouza.com.br/2018/01/face-recognition-in-oracle-cloud/).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do not store the raw images in the blob column. You should store the vector representation of raw images. The following python code block will find the vector representation of a face image.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface.basemodels import VGGFace, Facenet

model = VGGFace.loadModel() #you can use google facenet instead of vgg
target_size = model.layers[0].input_shape

#preprocess detects facial area and aligns it
img = functions.preprocess_face(img="img.jpg", target_size=target_size)

representation = model.predict(img)[0,:]
```

Here, you can either pass exact image path like img.jpg or the 3D array to img argument of preprocess_face. In this way, you will store the vector representations in the blob column of oracle database.

When you have a new face image, and want to find its identity in the database find its representation again.

```
#preprocess detects facial area and aligns it
target_img = functions.preprocess_face(img="target.jpg", target_size=target_size)

target_representation = model.predict(target_img )[0,:]
```

Now, you have the vector representation of the target image and vector representations of the database images. You need to find the similarity score of target image representation and each instance of database representations.

Euclidean distance is the easiest way to compare vectors.

```
def findEuclideanDistance(source_representation, test_representation):
    euclidean_distance = source_representation - test_representation
    euclidean_distance = np.sum(np.multiply(euclidean_distance, euclidean_distance))
    euclidean_distance = np.sqrt(euclidean_distance)
    return euclidean_distance
```

We will compare each data base instance to target. Suppose that representations of data base instances are stored in representations object.

```
distances = []
for i in range(0, len(representations)):
   source_representation = representations[i]
   #find the distance between target_representation and source_representation
   distance = findEuclideanDistance(source_representation, target_representation )
   distances.append(distance)
```

Distances list stores the distance of each item in the data base to target. We need to find the lowest distance.

```
import numpy as np
idx = np.argmax(distances)
```

Idx is the id of the target image in the database.